# Collect Document Text from Google Doc with Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I am working on an update finder for my application and I want it so I'll check the text in the document then it'll determine if it matches the current version. But I'm wondering on how to maybe extract the data then split the rest of the code away from '0.1'

Here's the web link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_VQOwm0jRLyZQzcUiOt65_OSBPBgNAaGLi5Oe6L0iZg/edit

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to extract the contents of the webpage with BeautifulSoup and urllib2/urllib.requests but when I tried it didn't work.

Comment: Don't post links to external documents — they become useless when the owner puts them in the trash.  No one can read your document any more.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the crucial information is no longer accessible so no one can benefit from seeing what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need to use a Google Doc document specifically, a spreadsheet would be a better solution.

```
from io import StringIO;
import requests;
url = "<your google sheets url here>";
r = requests.get(url + "/export?format=csv&gid=0");
data = r.content;
print(data);
```

an empty spreadsheet with "0.1" in the first cell returns b'0.1', which can be fixed with

```
data = r.content.decode().replace("b", "").replace("'", "");
```

Comment: Thanks for responding though I just created a spreadsheet then set '0.1' as its title and first cell, however, when using that code, the program printed incredibly long strips of text of the code of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Never mind, I know what I have to do; split the '0.1' away from the rest. Thanks!